# Date compare is not working in Aggregate using mongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have created query with date comparison in mongoDB which is working fine
but when I convert that query in PHP array and execute in aggregate method, It does not respond with any of data.

Following is mongoDB Query converted in PHP

```
 $dateStart = new MongoDate(strtotime("2016-06-08T18:30:00.000+0000"));

$pipeline = array(
    array('$match' => array(
        'EventTS' => array(
            '$gte' => $dateStart
         )
    ))
);
```

When I pass $pipeline  in aggregate

```
$t = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Sometime it respond empty records and sometime it respond with following error message

```
    Array
(
    [ok] => 0
    [errmsg] => aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)
    [code] => 16389
)
```

It seems my query is right but I am unable to identify what is the exact issue

Comment: kindly suggest any solution

Answer (score 1):

```
Your Query is perfect but as per mongodb define your document size more than 16 MB means your single row which is greater than 16 MB.

    For resolve this issue you need to use $project in aggregation that migh be solve these issue.
    Eg.

    $pipeline = array(
        array('$match' => array(
            'EventTS' => array(
                '$gte' => $dateStart
             )
        )),
        array('$project' => array('<field>'=>' <1 or true>'))
    );

OR you can use FINDALL

find(array('EventTS' => array( '$gte' => $dateStart )))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to above mentioned description,you just need to fetch all documents having date time greater than specific date time .

It can be accomplished easily utilizing find operation of MongoDB.

Aggregation is useful in cases where we need to perform some calculations on group of data.

Please try executing following code snippet

```
$date = new MongoDate(strtotime("2016-06-08T18:30:00.000+0000"));
$filter=array('EventTS'=>array('$gte'=>$date));
$data=$collection->find($filter);
```